# php inside HTML via shortcode?

Tags: php, forms

Previous two questions of mine lead up to this. Almost there, just need one more nudge :)
As a shortcode, I have this form (only problem inputs shown):

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value=<?php echo "'" . get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) . "'"; ?>>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value=<?php echo """ . get_the_ID() . """; ?>>
```

However the php isn't processing.
I think it is in the syntax. Any ideas?

Thanks for the patient help!

Comment: please improve your questions, give context, your full applicable code, and your debuging effort

Comment: @MarkKaplun applicable code was posted. The rest of the form was not relevant to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be changed to

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value=<?php echo "'" . get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) . "'"; ?>>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value=<?php echo "'" . get_the_ID() . "'"; ?>>
```

Based off the first input where you have " ' " and the second one you're using " " " will just return the a string with ". get_the_ID() ."

Comment: I'm just getting a start at this so my understanding of the proper syntax in such cases is weak. Your answer teaches me much. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. If this fixed it, mark as correct.

Comment: Sorry but how do I mark this as correct?? Using the app.

Comment: It should have a green check mark next to my answer. If you click on it, it marks the answer as correct. Thanks